# Почему выдаёт ошибку TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

**Код:**

```py
#value = b53344da40daf310e8d226f13798b45a

h = soup.find('table', {"class":"table", 'id':"order-listing"}).find_all('input')["value"]

print(h)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Я с BeautifulSoup не знаком, но одна вещь меня таки сильно настораживает... Это как вы так сделали `find_all('input')["value"]`? Вы сначала получили список всех инпутов....а потом пытаетесь сразу из списка извлечь `value`...о чем, вам по моему ошибка и говорит, что она на месте вашего `"value"` ждет целочисленный индекс или срез...

Comment: Вам там как минимум нужно `.find_all('input')[0]["value"]` или что-то в том роде...зависит от API BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

```
h = soup.find('table', {"class":"table", 'id':"order-listing"}).find_all('input')
```

вытаскиваеем все значения атрибутов "value" из тега 'input'

```
val =[x.get("value") for x in h]
```

Могу предположить, что все значения атрибутов "value" из тега 'input' одинаковые, тогда проще достать значение атрибута "value" из первого тега 'input'

```
h = soup.find('input')["value"]
```

или

```
h = soup.find('input').get("value")
```